# How to prevent not visible objects (scale rules) from being identified?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, rule-based, identify

In Symbology tab I am using rule-based symbols and I have defined visibility rules dependent on the minimum scale. Above some scale threshold some features are not visible as I expected. But **when I am clicking on not visible feature with identify tool it is still listed in the identify results.** How to prevent it?
[image]

[image]